# Ignore edges when calculating betweenness or closeness of the graph

Tags: python, networkx, igraph

I want to do calculation on my graph neglecting some edges (as if they don't exist). Like calculation of degree, closeness, or betweenness.

any ideas !

Python

Answer (score 1):

You could simply remove the edges you want to ignore before running the computations, and keep a record of what edges you have to put back when you're done.

Comment: I tried that, the problem when I add the edges again, the sequence of the edges is now changed and the results will not be consistent.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?  I don't believe the order of edges will matter in networkx, and certainly it shouldn't change the betweenness.

Comment: I need to pass the results of edge_betweenness of the edges to another function. I need them to be with the same order. Right now, I used OrderDict (Dictionary) so the dict.values()  is the edge_betweenness. Thanks for replying :)  I am just asking if there is a nicer way to do it.

Comment: @TamerIbrahim could you avoid relying on ordering to index your data? For example, you could have an edge dictionary whose keys are the node pairs that an edge connects:  `{(node1, node2): edge_betweenness}`. You could then add and remove edges from that data structure. If your function down the lines expects a certain order, then you could rewrite it to remove that assumption.

Comment: @HugoMailhot Thanks for your response, I actually used OrderedDict the same way you mentioned.

Comment: Glad I could help! If my answer worked for you, you should mark it as accepted so that the question doesn't appear unanswered.